# Google Cloud Speech in Node.JS: config speech_context

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

I'm using the Node.JS variation of the Google Speech API.

All works well and dandy until I dare pass in an array of strings `speech_context` parameter. When I try in each of the below ways the stream interrupts, but **no error** is emitted. Thus there's no way for me to diagnose.

I am passing an array of strings `["one", "two", "three"]`, abiding to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.RecognitionConfig), so I believe. My original configuration looks like this:

```
const cf = {
    config: {
        encoding: 'LINEAR16',
        sampleRate: 48000
    }
}
```

I have tried `cf.config.speech_context = ARRAY`, `cf.config.speech_context.phrases = ARRAY`, `cf.speech_context = ARRAY`, and `cf.speech_context.phrases = ARRAY`.

Again, I get no error message, nor do I get a result. I get nothing. The original config on its own **works**.

This with a basic stream:

```
recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(cf)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', console.log)
```

Ideas? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
    const request = {
    config: {
      encoding: encoding,
      sampleRate: sampleRate,
      languageCode:'en-IN-x-longform',
    }
  };

  // Stream the audio to the Google Cloud Speech API

  const recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(request)
    .on('error', (error) => {
         console.error;
     })
    .on('data', (data) => {
      console.log('Data received: %j', data);
      if('results' in data)
        console.log(chalk.bgYellow( data.results ));
      logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });



  // Stream an audio file from disk to the Speech API, e.g.    "./resources/audio.raw"

   filename = "./resources/audio.raw";
   fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(recognizeStream);



 //This is working for me
 //I think you are missing the pipe part in , so you can do

 recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(cf)
      .on('error', console.error)
      .on('data', console.log)

   filename = "./resources/audio.raw";
   fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(recognizeStream);

`
```